# Immersive mode without app context

Tags: java, android

I am able to hide status bar and navigation bar when the app is on foreground but what I need is to hide or show system bars even if the app is in the background and another application is opened.

This is what I want

**First time if the user has opened the application then he can see the floating button even he kills the application. Now If the user will try to open any other application, for example, the user has open google chrome still we don't need to show status bar. but if the user again taps on the floating button then status bar will be visible.
So Floating button will be like a switch for turning on and off the status bar.**

I have a floating icon on tap should toggle immersive mode even if the app is in the background.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

I have tried with service it is working with the app when running in the foreground.

Comment: Do *not* indent text with four spaces as it will be treated as code.

Comment: can any one help me to find the solution ?

Comment: Your question is not answer, because it lacks crucial information. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist how to ask a good question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how to ask and always try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please update your question and it will be answered hopefully.